# How can i gracefully interrupt a stream from HTTP in Java?

Tags: java, http, thread-safety, interrupt

I'm running a Java code that listen to a long polling HTTP stream.
This is the method I'm using.

```
void connectStream() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("...");

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (null != entity) {
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader((entity.getContent()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I need to interrupt gracefully this stream from the main thread. What is the best way to do it?
For now, I'm adding an `AtomicBoolean` variable and check it in each iteration of the loop.

```
private AtomicBoolean interrupt = new AtomicBoolean(false);

void connectStream() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("...");

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (null != entity) {
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader((entity.getContent()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (interrupt.get()) {
                break;
            }
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}

public void setInterrupt() {
    this.interrupt.set(true);
}
```

This works well when the buffer often contains data. But what if the buffer remains empty for a long time?

I've already tried to close `stream` and `reader`: the program does not execute the code inside the loop any more it does not exit from it.

Comment: Hi @AlessioPalmeroAprosio - You need to know the thread that is blocked and interrupt it. `httpThread.interrupt()`..  If there's a 1-1 relationship between connnections and instances of whatever the class is you could save it .. and then `setInterrupt()` could call it, but if not you'll need to say create a `FutureTask` or something like that and then use those ..

Comment: When you say "interrupt" do you mean (a) terminate processing of the incoming stream, discarding any remaining data, or (b) temporarily pause processing but resume later from the same point?  I am guessing you mean (a) based on the code but please clarify is that's not the case.  If it's (a), and you're blocked in `reader.readLine()`, then the thread cannot be interrupted.

Comment: From the code it looks like each invocation of `connectStream()` is intended to issue a `get` request and then process all data returned by the server.  You could run each such invocation in its own thread, and not worry about it pausing when no data is available.  Each such thread would eventually terminate when the server closes the connection and the `readLine()` throws an IO Exception.

Comment: @MrR Interrupting a thread does not unblock `InputStream.read()`.

Comment: Hmm good point - @user207421 - What about via `Stream.close()` [I haven't tried but ...] - it kind of feels awful but in theory it's not a lot different than the other end dying ...

Comment: @JimGarrison - threads do have a cost - but that's one reason why Executors exist .. to "share" the cost around ...

Comment: @MrR I don't know what is blocking the thread, but if I use the `break` as in second solution everything works as expected (and the thread dies gracefully). I also tried `stream.close()` and `reader.close()`: it stops to execute the code in the loop, but it does not exit.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't think this would change its behavior: the threads will exit but the `while` stays hung up, I guess.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any other way to perform a GET HTTP stream request so that I can kill it at any time?

Comment: Looks like Java v16 introduced cancelable futures which might help if you're okay with cancelling the specific HTTP request thread.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252515

Comment: Also looks like OkHTTP has added support for listening for thread interruptions:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I could find a way to get the socket underlying the HTTP connection. By closing it, the thread quits correctly.

```
// No need this anymore
// private AtomicBoolean interrupt = new AtomicBoolean(false);

// New
private Socket socket;

void connectStream() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("...");

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());

    // New block code here
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
    ManagedHttpClientConnection connection = context.getConnection(ManagedHttpClientConnection.class);
    socket = connection.getSocket();

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (null != entity) {
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader((entity.getContent()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}

public void setInterrupt() {
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```